# Https and http both the protocals not able to run in websphere liberty server with springboot

Tags: spring-security

I want to run the health check of the services only with http and all the services as https. facing the issue to configure the particular URI with in-secure protocal (http). tried below but its not working:

Here I am trying to configure the healthcheck with http and all the services with https :

```
http.requiresChannel().antMatchers("*/healthcheck").requiresInsecure().anyRequest().requiresSecure();
```

Please help me to resolve this  issue

Thanks in advance.

Comment: when I am hitting the url like https://localhost:4450/services/healthcheck, its not redirecting to the http://localhost:9080/services/healthcheck as I have configured */healthcheck as in-secure.

Comment: The Above issue is resolved by adding below:

Comment: <hostAlias>${HostName}:${HTTPS_PORT}</hostAlias>
<hostAlias>${HostName}:${HTTP_PORT}</hostAlias> inside the vertual host.

Comment: Now getting below exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: @Order on WebSecurityConfigurers must be unique

Comment: I have tried with @Order(anotherIntegreNumber) but its again giving same exception like: java.lang.IllegalStateException: @Order on WebSecurityConfigurers must be unique. Order of AnotherIntegerNumber